# Calculate the time

Tags: python

I had 2 things to do here,

1. Print start time and end time.
2. Calculate time.

```
import datetime
import re

logs = "432894u2398 start 7:00:00.100" , "432894u2398 end 7:03:24.400"

start_regex = r'start\s(\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)'

end_regex = r'end\s(\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)'


for line in logs:
    sr = re.search(start_regex, line)
    er = re.search(end_regex, line)
    if sr:
        print(f'transaction start time is: {sr.group(1)}')
    if er:
        print(f'transaction end time is: {er.group(1)}')
```

How do I calculate the time difference between them?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate time"? Do you mean the time difference?

Comment: Use `datetime.strptime()` to parse the times. Then subtract them to get the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
import re

start, end = "432894u2398 start 7:00:00.100" , "432894u2398 end 7:03:24.400"

get_time_string = lambda s: re.split(r"(start|end) ", s)[2]
to_date = lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(get_time_string(s), '%H:%M:%S.%f')

delta = to_date(end) - to_date(start)
print(delta)
## 0:03:24.3000000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the log messages are always the same format, you could make your life easier by doing this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Get the times out of the log message and parse them
start, end = list(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.rsplit(" ")[1], "%H:%M:%S.%f"), logs))
# Calculate duration by subtracting datetimes
duration = end - start
```